# cancel a click event on a DOM element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible, with Jquery, to cancel a click event on a DOM element that will be called after this cancel code? The aim is to override any click event, even if it comes later in the code.

thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery("#mydiv").click(function(e){
        // here how to  disable all other click events on #mydiv, called after or before this function and execute only lines below on click event
    })      
});
```

Comment: Can you share some code?  It's hard to offer coding suggestions or improvements when you haven't shown any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty solution is to replace #mydiv with a clone of itself, just change the ID.

Since mydiv will no longer be in the DOM, the click handler for it won't register on click.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#mydiv").replaceWith(jQuery("#mydiv").clone().prop("id","mydiv2"));
  
  jQuery("#mydiv2").click(function(e) {
    console.log("test 1");
  })

  jQuery("#mydiv").click(function(e) {
    console.log("test 2");
  })
});
```

```css
#mydiv2{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">Test</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `replaceWith()` be inside the click handler on `#mydiv`?